# Get all the urls under domain (YQL?)

Tags: screen-scraping, sitemap, yql

I want to get all the urls under a domain.
When I looked at their robots.txt. It clearly states that some of the folders are not for robots but I am wondering is there a way to get the all the urls that are open to robots. There is no sitemap on the robots.txt.

For example, on their robots.txt, it has the information looks similar like this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /A/
Disallow: /B/
Disallow: /C/
...
```

But I am interested in all the urls available to the robots but not included in this blacklist, like

```
/contact
/welcome
/product1
/product2
...
```

Any idea will be appreicated and I am also curious if there will be a Yahoo Query Language(YQL) solution for this problem because this work has probably already been done by Yahoo.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is a way to get all the urls open to robots.

A simple solution would be to go to www.google.com and type site:www.website.com into the search bar.

While that isn't a guarantee to get you every page it will get you all the pages google has indexed.  And google adhered to robots.txt so it seems to fit your purpose.

Comment: that is a great idea, but does that mean I have to scrape google first to collect the urls, which is actually a hard job because google has some pretty good anti-scraping techniques to stop people Scraping google. Do you know if I could do that in YQL easily?

Comment: Dont know if you can do it YQL or not.  I dont use it much.  You can only see on the internet what people decide to show you.  They can show you by a site map or even just links on their home page.  Your only other option I know of would be to sit there and guess url's to go into the url bar.  Which is obviously a crappy solution.

Screen scrapers to find <a> tags seems to be your next step!